# Counting by changing signs in a $K \times K$ grid

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

Let $A$ be a $K \times K$ grid, where all the elements are $1$.

We define an operation as changing the sign of all the elements in a certain row or column.

If, after several operations, there are exactly $n$ elements equal to $-1$, we call $n$ a "good number".

Find the total number of "good numbers".

---

My Progress:

Noting that the final grid only contains elements $1$ and $-1$, the count of $-1$ elements corresponds one-to-one with the total sum of elements in the grid. So I think it is possible to calculate the number of possible different sums.

In the specific case $10 \times 10$ the sums are $\left\{0, ±4, ±8, ±12, ±16, ±20, ±24, ±32,
± 40, ±36, ±48, ±60, ±64, ±80, ±100\right\}$, so the answer to this case is the rank of the set, that is $29$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does this problem come from?

Comment: Hint: Note that the order you flip the rows and columns does not matter, and flipping the same column/row twice has no effect. We can therefore assume that each row/column is flipped at most once. Let $r$ be the number of rows which were flipped, and $c$ the number of columns which were flipped. The hint is to figure out the number of elements equal to $-1$, as a function of $r$ and $c$. Hint 2: to make the counting easier, count the number of $-1$'s when you flip the leftmost $c$ columns, and topmost $r$ rows. Then, prove you get the same number when you flip any $r$ rows and $c$ columns.